# Swift 4 - How can I call a piece of code which returns out of the function in multiple functions without duplicating code?

Tags: swift, swift4, nsurlsession, urlsession

I am working with a poorly designed API (I don't have control over it) where even if the access token is expired, it still returns a HTTP success code but includes the 401 Unauthorized in the actual response body. So simply checking the HTTP status code isn't sufficient and I need to check the actual response.

I am making many network requests in my app to this API and when I receive the response, I need to first check whether the response is an array or a dictionary. If array, then we are good. If it's a dictionary, then I need to check the "error" field in the response dictionary which will have the 401 Unauthorized.

So every time I receive the JSON response, I have the following piece of code to return out of the function if it's an error dictionary:

```
guard !(myJSON is NSDictionary) &&  (myJSON as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "error") != nil else {
                    print("Error: ", MyAppError.accessTokenExpired)
                    return
                }
```

I am wondering if there is a way to prevent duplicating this piece of code in every network request function I have? Can I have this somewhere and simply call it without duplicating these lines of code each time?

Comment: `NSDictionary` is horrible, `value(forKey` is horrible, check `is && as! ... != nil` is horrible.

Comment: @vadian is there a better way to do the check? I am brand new to Swift.

Comment: `if` is better in this case. `if let dictionary = myJSON as? [String:Any], dictionary["error"] != nil { print("Error: .... return }`

Comment: Any specific reason/how does one decide if let is better than guard?

Comment: `guard` is useful if you want to keep an optional bound value which is not the case.

Comment: Ideally, you should not be generating a dictionary at all here; you should have a Codable struct that decodes the response. A data type that includes "Any" is always going to be a nightmare. So the better place to start is back at the point that you're creating `myJSON` in the first place, and we can help you parse that better. Then this problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a function like this one

```
func isErrorResponse(_ response: Any) -> Bool {
    if let dict = response as? [String: Any], let error = dict["error"] {
        print("Error: \(MyAppError.accessTokenExpired)")
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: I had to change the `Dictionary` to `[String:Any]` as else it was giving an error

Answer (score 0):

You should use the swift data types if you are using Swift language. Although if `myJSON` validates with `Dictionary` then it will definitely be validated with `[String: Any]`.

Create function like:

```
func isValidResponse(_ json: Any) -> Bool {
    guard let jsonDict = json as? [String: Any], let let error = dict["error"] else { return true }
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return false
}
```

Use it as:

```
guard YourClass.isValidResponse(myJSON) else { return }

// Valid Response - Code here...
```